# Does Google index AJAX websites after running the JavaScript?

Tags: seo, googlebot, ajax, single-page-application

As I understand [Google depreciated its ajax crawling scheme](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) they came up with back in 2009. I run single page app powered by Anguar frontend with push state navigation and my question is around webmaster tools.

There are two buttons in `Fetch as Google`. `Fetch` and `Fetch and Render`. When I click `Fetch and Render` I receive two screenshots under the `Rendering` tab and these match almost perfectly.
Looking at the other `Fetching` tab I can see the code Google downloaded from my site. This however is not reflecting changes that should happen after my JavaScript run.

So my question is which content Google will use to index my site? As I understand it, the rendered content will be used. So whatever the screen shots show will be indexed, not the HTML that only says "Fetching".   If that's the case, it would make my life beautiful again without need to render snapshots on server side or use `_escaped_fragment`s.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch as Google acts like preview and shows your site with not executed, partly executed or fully executed javascript, dependently on timepoint of javascript execution (before `onload`, just after `onload`, fat time gap after `onload`). Google cache shows your site with fully executed javascript.

**Update** 24.07.2016: Screaming Frog integrated the Chromium engine into its crawler, so it is now possible to fully imitate the googlebot crawling behavior, even with adjusting the time gap after `onLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Google is very good at interpreting javascript/jquery even for the evaluation of backlinks. I suspect that they will use the data on the left hand side of the screenshot titled "This is how Googlebot saw the page:" for gathering content and the right to ensure that you are giving the correct content to users. Since the render on both parts is exactly the same i think you should be fine. I'm a little old school and like to see content in the source however i can't see why Google would frown upon excellent content delivered in this way because otherwise they wouldn't be putting the effort to developing their indexing strategies to suit this.